# PHP if then else inside an array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

Sorry for repeated (no doubt) question, but other answers have slightly confused me.

So I have an array like this:

```
$testflag = '';

    $test = array(

    'auxiliaryFields' => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'extra1',
            'label' => 'TEST',
            'value' => 'TEST',
            'textAlignment' => 'PKTextAlignmentLeft'                
        )
        if ($testflag != ''){
        ,
        array(
            'key'   => 'extra2',
            'label' => 'TEST2',
            'value' => 'TEST2',
            'textAlignment' => 'PKTextAlignmentLeft'                
        )
    }

    ));

    var_dump($test);
```

Now, I've read that you can't use code inside an array, so my question is how to do the above?  In this example it's just 2 arrays (extra1 & extra2) but I have 4 arrays in total in my actual code.  The condition is basically if session:form:element:not_null then include extra2 - 3 - 4 and so on, if it IS null, do nothing.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Not possible using a single outer `array` expression (and this is a duplicate). `?:` usage will result in *a* value, but cannot specify "an absence of a value".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329897/if-statement-within-an-array-declaration-is-that-possible?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665068/using-an-if-else-within-an-array?rq=1

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Your question is confusion because you’re trying to explain how to do something without context. Obviously conditional statements within an array isn’t possible, so chances are there’s a more elegant solution if you actually detail your problem.

Comment: Hi Martin: Ok, I've implemented PHP-PKPass into a script I'm building.  I've got a form that upon submission redirects to the passbook pass creation script.  The vars are passed into the form and then broken down to match the arrays in the script.  Inside the auxiliaryFields array is 4 more arrays (2 shown in demo) but if the data that would populate array 2,3 and 4 is not present I need to skip those areas

Comment: I tried array_push but that didn't work (or I did it wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to mzedeler answer but it work

```
$testflag = 'test';

$test = array(

'auxiliaryFields' => array(
    array(
        'key'   => 'extra1',
        'label' => 'TEST',
        'value' => 'TEST',
        'textAlignment' => 'PKTextAlignmentLeft'                
    )
));

var_dump($test);
if ($testflag != ''){
    $test['auxiliaryFields'][]=array(
        'key'   => 'extra2',
        'label' => 'TEST2',
        'value' => 'TEST2',
        'textAlignment' => 'PKTextAlignmentLeft'                
    );
}

var_dump($test);
```

I've changed $test['auxiliaryFields'][0][] with $test['auxiliaryFields'][] and fixed a sintax error (missing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
    $testflag = '';

    $test = array(

    'auxiliaryFields' => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'extra1',
            'label' => 'TEST',
            'value' => 'TEST',
            'textAlignment' => 'PKTextAlignmentLeft'                
        )
    ));
    if ($testflag != '') {
        $test['auxillaryFields'][] = 
        array(
            'key'   => 'extra2',
            'label' => 'TEST2',
            'value' => 'TEST2',
            'textAlignment' => 'PKTextAlignmentLeft'                
        )
    }
```

Comment: its must be `$test['auxillaryFields'][]` instead of `$test['auxillaryFields'][0][]` i think

Comment: Sorry. No. I've just re-inserted a bracket that was confusing me. You are right. Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a conditional in an array as you've done in your snippet. You can add extra values to an array after the array is declared.

For example

```
if (something) {
   $test[] = $someArray;  // $test[] is next element, so 
                          // add $someArray as next element of $test 
}
```

Your snippet becomes:

$testflag = '';

```
// set up array here
$test = array(

'auxiliaryFields' => array(
    array(
        'key'   => 'extra1',
        'label' => 'TEST',
        'value' => 'TEST',
        'textAlignment' => 'PKTextAlignmentLeft'                
    )
);

// conditionally, add an extra element.
if ($testflag != ''){
    $test[] = 
        array(
        'key'   => 'extra2',
        'label' => 'TEST2',
        'value' => 'TEST2',
        'textAlignment' => 'PKTextAlignmentLeft'                
    );
}



var_dump($test);
```