# How to use the ternary operator in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, ternary-operator

I am trying to figure out how I can use the ternary operator in my array. I want to be able to check if the value matches then make that option `"selected"`.

Here is my code:

```
<select id="time_out_1" name="data[<?= $id;?>][time_out]">

<?php

$miltimes = array("<option value=\"0000\">0000</option>","<option value=\"0030\">0030</option>",   "<option value=\"0100\">0100</option>",   "<option value=\"0130\">0130</option>",   "<option value=\"0200\">0200</option>",   "<option value=\"0230\">0230</option>",   
"<option value=\"0300\">0300</option>",   "<option value=\"0330\">0330</option>",   "<option value=\"0400\">0400</option>",  "<option value=\"0430\">0430</option>",   "<option value=\"0500\">0500</option>",   "<option value=\"0530\">0530</option>",   "<option value=\"0600\">0600</option>",   "<option value=\"0630\">0630</option>",   "<option value=\"0700\">0700</option>",   "<option value=\"0730\">0730</option>",   "<option value=\"0800\">0800</option>",   "<option value=\"0830\">0830</option>",   "<option value=\"0900\">0900</option>",   "<option value=\"0930\">0930</option>",   "<option value=\"1000\">1000</option>",   "<option value=\"1030\">1030</option>",   
"<option value=\"1100\">1100</option>",   "<option value=\"1130\">1130</option>",   "<option value=\"1200\">1200</option>",   "<option value=\"1230\">1230</option>",   "<option value=\"1300\">1300</option>",   "<option value=\"1330\">1330</option>",   "<option value=\"1400\">1400</option>",   "<option value=\"1430\">1430</option>",   "<option value=\"1500\">1500</option>",   "<option value=\"1530\">1530</option>",   "<option value=\"1600\">1600</option>",   "<option value=\"1630\">1630</option>",   "<option value=\"1700\">1700</option>",   "<option value=\"1730\">1730</option>",   "<option value=\"1800\">1800</option>",   "<option value=\"1830\">1830</option>",   "<option value=\"1900\">1900</option>",   "<option value=\"1930\">1930</option>",   "<option value=\"2000\">2000</option>", "<option value=\"2030\">2030</option>",      "<option value=\"2100\">2100</option>",      "<option value=\"2130\">2130</option>",      "<option value=\"2200\">2200</option>",      "<option value=\"2230\">2230</option>",      "<option value=\"2300\">2300</option>",      "<option value=\"2330\">2330</option>");

foreach($miltimes as $miltime) { echo $miltime; } 
echo '</select>';?>
```

I found this answer but I am not quite sure how to use it in my situation.

[Using an If-else within an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665068/using-an-if-else-within-an-array)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You should effect that in the loop, not in the array declaration. Also use an id list rather than a HTML output collection.

Comment: Yah I tried to use the foreach loop to echo the military time and add 30 minutes to each one but I could not get PHP to recognize `0000` as a starting referrence and `2330` as the end.

Comment: You can have the array contain strings still, no need for calculating them. `array("0000", "0030", "0130", "2200", "2230", );`

Comment: Ahh why didn't I think of that LOL. Let me give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: Just as a heads up -- the order of operation in PHP is broken. The `?` operator acts much differently than in other C-type language.  Either use a lot of parens or (better) don't use the thing at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting all your options tags in the array, you can just put the numbers and use PHP to create the tags for you:

```
$miltimes = array('0000', '0030', '0100', '0130', '0200', '0230', '0300', '0330', '0400', '0430', '0500', '0530', '0600', '0630', '0700', '0730', '0800', '0830', '0900', '0930', '1000', '1030', '1100', '1130', '1200', '1230', '1300', '1330', '1400', '1430', '1500', '1530', '1600', '1630', '1700', '1730', '1800', '1830', '1900', '1930', '2000', '2030', '2100', '2130', '2200', '2230', '2300', '2330');
$select = '<select id="time_out_1" name="'.$data[$id]['time_out']."\">\n";
foreach ($miltimes as $key => $value){
    $selected = ($value == '0030') ? ' selected' : '';
    $select .= "\t<option value=\"$value\"$selected>$value</option>\n";
}
$select .= "</select>\n";
echo $select;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set a time based on the values and if your time values are strings then

```
$matchtime = "1000";
$defaulttime = "0500"

foreach($miltimes as $miltime) { 
    $timematched = ($miltime == $matchtime) ? $miltime : $defaulttime;
    echo $timematched; 
}
```

Although it is better to have **only** time values in your array and to use a built-in function like [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) when comparing time. That way you wont be making string comparisons.

Comment: The values are preset in military time not `10:00'

Comment: You could use built in functions @Chris78 because your current array as i see it has html elements `<option>` so it will do a string comparison .. its better to seperate the html from the array. Check the edit above.